# SQL Server 2005: Schedule Start/Stop of TSQL Script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Currently running SQL 2005 on Server 2005. I have a TSQL script which updates 1000 rows at a time. It loops through a counter until there are no rows to update.

In my situation, I have a lot of rows to update and I need to run this "after hours". So I would like to see if there is a way that I can schedule a way to automatically start and stop a task based upon a set time. I am thinking that I could place this task in a SP and start it with SQL Agent. However, I can not think of how to stop the task automatically. I'm open to SSIS too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`SQL Job`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx), and make this call a `stored procedure` or some `sql`.  The job can be set on a timer, for specific days etc.

See [Creating a Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for help

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule following T-SQL to stop jab as well.

```
 USE msdb ;
 GO
 EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N'Your job name' ;
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182793.aspx